# Qual a diferença entre aplicações multi-layer e multi-tier?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

Qual a diferença entre aplicações multi-layer e multi-tier? Uma depende da outra?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Layers vs. Tiers

As pessoas normalmente intercambiam os dois termos para descrever uma mesma arquitetura como multi-layered e multi-tiered, simultaneamente. Isso não é exatamente verdade.

Adaptando a distinção feita pelo [App Arch Guide](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=apparch), **layers** se referem ao tipo-componente, as lógicas da Aplicação, enquanto **tiers** (2-tier, 3-tier, N-tier) se referem a distribuição física dos padrões. Fica particularmente fácil de compreender quando falando onde (em qual *tier*) sua *layer* será executada.

### Presentation Layer, Business Layer e Data Layer

Apesar de haver variações nos termos usados, muitas pessoas que constroem Aplicações identificam a *Presentation Layer* (Apresentação), *Business Layer* (Regras de Negócio) e *Data Layer* (Acesso aos Dados). Uma imagem vale mais que mil palavras, então:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- *Presentation Layer* (Apresentação): Oferece acesso interativo à Aplicação.
- *Business Layer* (Regras de Negócio): O agrupamento lógico de componentes e serviços que provêem funcionalidade à Aplicação.
- *Data Layer* (Acesso aos Dados): O agrupamento lógico de componentes que provêem acesso aos dados da Aplicação, estejam eles armazenados num banco de dados ou sejam fornecidos por um webService.

### 2-Tier, 3-Tier, e N-Tier

Como dito, as *tiers* são as representações físicas dos padrões a serem distribuídos. Não adianta ficar repetindo se não fizer sentido prático, então vamos ver os padrões mais comuns traduzidos em imagens:

*2-tiers*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisei um pouco a respeito e a definição mais sensata a que eu cheguei se refere a Intranets, onde a Aplicação precisa ser instalada em cada Estação e todas elas individualmente se comunicam com um único servidor.

Como vantagem temos a facilidade de compreensão da arquitetura. Mas como desvantagens temos, além do inconveniente da individualidade nesse caso, temos a lentidão quando muitas Estações estiverem operando a Aplicação simultaneamente.

*3-tiers*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A mais comum, popularizada pelo MVC, define a camada de apresentação apenas para definir os elementos visuais através dos quais a Aplicação será operada.

A camada "intermediária" intermeia de forma mais rápida as requisições feitas pelo Usuário com os dados da terceira camada, onde residem os dados.

Note a distinção entre **onde** residem os dados e **os dados** propriamente ditos, o que reforça a diferença entre *layer* (lógica) e *tier* (física) dita anteriormente.

*N-tier*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mais difícil de descrever em um exemplo, mas eu diria que Autenticação por Serviço cabe direitinho.

O Cliente decide que quer se autenticar no Stack Overflow PT com sua conta do Google, a Aplicação se comunica com o serviço Google Auth, este retorna às Regras de Negócio da Aplicação que usa o endereço de e-mail do autenticado como condicional para obter as respostas e comentários feitos.

### Recursos Adicionais

- [Aplicações em Camadas (*layers*)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650258(v=pandp.10))
- [Distribuições em camadas (*tiers*)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff647195(v=pandp.10))
- [Distrbuição *3-tiers*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa480039(v=msdn.10))
- [Escolhendo a Arquitetura de Apresentação Apropriada](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa480039(v=msdn.10))

Artigo Original: [J. D. Meier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmeier/layers-and-tiers)

Tradução e Adaptação: Um estranho qualquer chamado Bruno Augusto :P

Answer (score 4):

Resposta trazida no SOEN (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120438/whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers)

> **Layers** são uma forma de organizar seu código. Tipicamente, layers
>   incluem, apresentação, negócios, dados, que é basicamente o conceito
>   de 3 camadas. Mas layer não significa que seja outro processo,
>   computador, cluster. Layers são divisões lógicas do código de acordo
>   com suas funções.
>
> **Tiers** no entanto é sobre onde o código executa. Tiers são os locais
>   onde as Layers são colocadas e onde elas rodam. Tier portanto é o
>   deploy físico onde as Layers rodam.

Eu não traduzi os termos pois, em português tudo é chamado de camadas. Mas em resumo, Layers são **camadas lógicas** e Tier **camadas físicas**.