# O que realmente é uma aplicação N-tier?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

Sempre ouvi muito falar sobre aplicações N-tier, mas pensando sobre o assunto ultimamente fiquei um pouco confuso com o que isso realmente significa. Pesquisando no google achei o artigo do wikipedia sobre o assunto e vi que isso tem a ver com uma separação física.

Então dessa forma, uma aplicação N-tier é uma aplicação que é dividida em N partes sendo que cada uma roda em um ambiente distinto? Então uma aplicação web com acesso a base de dados seria considerada 3-tier por ser dividida em client, server e base de dados, sendo que cada um funciona em um lugar?

Mas nesse caso se o servidor de base de dados estiver no mesmo computador que o servidor web, aí seria 2-tier? Ou o que conta é que são processos separados?

Comment: Eu só vi até hoje o uso de tier para categorizar nível de datacenter

Comment: Tier é camada que representa uma sequencia lógica, ponto. 
Você pode criar uma aplicação de 1..N camadas, da forma que você achar que é o correto. Isso nao significa que é algo físico ou em ambientes separados. é somente a separação abstrata de sua aplicação.

Comment: @JosuéEduardo Isso que você disse, com um pouco mais de detalhes, daria uma boa resposta para postar ali embaixo ;)

Comment: Não é exatamente uma duplicata, mas tem uma resposta bacana de um cara que eu nunca ouvi falar [nesse tópico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22482).

Comment: É uma abordagem, mas não o único prisma que se pode considerar o nível de camadas de uma aplicação.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:**

**Tier** geralmente se referencia a **camada física**, enquanto **layer** geralmente se referencia a camada lógica. Isso é um conceito mais antigo, hoje basicamente, a maioria dos servidores rodam na núvem, onde essa "separação física" não faz muito sentido. 
Irei tratar Tier e Layer como o mesmo sentido da palavra (camada / nível)

Tier / Layer é camada que representa uma sequencia lógica, ponto. Você pode criar uma aplicação de 1..N camadas, da forma que você achar que é o correto. Isso nao significa necessariamente que é algo físico ou em ambientes separados. é somente a separação abstrata de sua aplicação em sí.
Por exemplo hoje em dia é bem conhecido aplicações em 3 camadas... ([não confundir com MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698220/mvc-vs-n-tier-architecture)).

**Só para ilustrar:**

**Camada 1:** Camada de apresentação, onde fica tudo relacionado a view, pode ser telas do Java Swing, Forms do .Net, ou paginas web.

**Camada 2:** Camada de lógica. Todas as regras específicas de sua aplicação, é a parte central de sua app. Onde de fato você está concebendo suas idéias.

**Camada 3:** Acesso ao banco. Bom aqui, você... acessa o banco =). E também pode haver alguma lógica relacionado à transação, etc.

Nada te impede de criar uma app com 1,2,3,4 ou  5+ camadas, por exemplo as 3 acimas citadas, mais outra de integração Rest, outra específica de validação e por ai vai. Tudo depende do requerimento do projeto. Em geral 3 é o suficiente ou até demais.

**Porque usar camadas ?**

Na prática é para separar os conceitos. **Geralmente** é feito a comunicação através de [interfaces](http://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-interfaces-programacao-orientada-a-objetos-parte-1/18695), oque facilita muito caso precise adicionar ou substituir uma delas. Outra situação é quando se trabalha em equipe. Onde você tem os carinhas do frontend desenvolvendo a interface gráfica, outros no "core", etc. Onde cada equipe não altera o código da outra equipe, tudo isso trabalhando em cima do mesmo projeto. E ao mesmo tempo eles sabem oque passar e oque receber da camada superior/ inferior por utilizarem os contratos das interfaces. Tudo isso no mundo de POO, outros paradgmas não sei bem ao certo como deve funcionar.

Frisando que "camada" é a separação abstrata da lógica de seu projeto. Porém quando se tratando de grandes arquiteturas, podemos também ter N camadas, a nivel de aplicação, onde cada camada pode corresponder a uma aplicação rodando em um servidor, que se comunica com outro rodando em outro servidor,  um bom exemplo disso são aplicações comercias, onde as coisas começam a ficar bem grandes.

Em geral mais camadas não significa ser melhor,  quanto mais camadas, mais desacoplamento você tem, oque é bom mas muitas vezes desnecessário, porém gera uma maior complexidade e trabalho na manutenção.

Note que camada possui o esquema de pilha, onde para chegar a última você deve passar por todas as intermediárias, ex:

**camada 1 <-> camada 2 <-> camada 3**

Comment: Na verdade, "N-Tier" refere-se sim à separação física de conceitos e só esporadicamente um sistema N-Tier não usa mais do que uma máquina em produção, pois a arquitetura é toda projetada para ser implantada em mais de uma máquina. Não confundir "N-Tier" com "Multi Layer", este último sim dizendo respeito somente à separação lógica dos conceitos e não necessariamente sua separação física.

Comment: Se for realmente uma camada física seria interessante reformular a resposta, caso for lógica colocar alguma referência.

Comment: Somente frisando a informação referente a layer x tier:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120438/whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers

Comment: @JosuéEduardo Ou seja: "Isso nao significa necessariamente que é algo físico ou em ambientes separados" é uma afirmação **incorreta** em se tratando de "tiers".

Comment: @Caffé Atualizado as definições, Obrigado

Answer (score 7):

Uma aplicação N-Tier, é um programa de aplicação em n camadas é um aplicativo desenvolvido de forma a ter várias camadas lógicas. Cada camada é auto-contida o suficiente de forma que a aplicação pode ser dividida em vários computadores em uma rede distribuída.

A forma mais comum da arquitetura é a aplicação em três camadas (3-Tier), comumente usada em aplicações web, na qual as camadas são:

- interface com o usuário (Camada de Apresentação);
- lógica do negócio (Camada de Negócio); e
- banco de dados (Camada de Dados).

Cada camada desta arquitetura é normalmente mantida em um servidor específico para tornar-se mais escalonável e independente das demais. Com o mesmo objetivo são utilizadas tecnologias de middleware como, por exemplo, CORBA, Web Services ou RMI.

Esta arquitetura tem como características:

- Baixos custos de disponibilização;
- Baixos custos na mudança da base de dados;
- Baixos custos na mudança da lógica de negócios;
- Eficiente armazenamento e reutilização de recursos.

É discutível que conta como "camadas", mas na minha opinião ele precisa pelo menos cruzar a fronteira processo. Ou então ele é chamado de camadas. Mas, isto não necessita de ser em máquinas fisicamente diferentes. Embora eu não recomendo, você pode hospedar camadas e banco de dados lógico na mesma caixa.

[image: Exemplo de aplicação 3-tier]

Uma implicação é que camada de apresentação e a camada lógica (às vezes chamado Business Logic Layer) precisa atravessar fronteiras "pelo fio" às vezes por rede não confiável, lento, e / ou inseguro. Isso é muito diferente da aplicação desktop simples, onde os dados residem na mesma máquina como arquivos ou aplicativos da Web onde você pode acessar o banco de dados diretamente.

Para programação n-tier, você precisa empacotar os dados em algum tipo de forma transportável chamado de "conjunto de dados", e levá-los ao longo do fio. A Classe DataSet do .Net ou Web Services como o SOAP são poucos de tais tentativas de "passar" objetos ao longo do fio.

Comment: Boa resposta. Algumas obs: a) N-Tier não se refere apenas a camadas lógicas mas sim a camadas físicas de fato. b) Vai ser muito difícil você encontrar um aplicativo web "acessando o banco de dados diretamente"; exitem frameworks que tratam o acesso aos dados de maneira muito transparente, mas na prática você sempre terá no mínimo duas camadas: o navegador web e o servidor de aplicativos que recebeu a requisição e devolveu alguma coisa (html, json, xml, etc). E raramente este servidor de aplicativos estará gerenciando o banco de dados - na maioria das vezes ele consumirá um SGBD (daí: 3-Tiers).

Answer (score 2):

Aplicação N-Tier é uma aplicação cuja arquitetura separa conceitos **fisicamente**. "N-Tier" não se refere a separação lógica ou conceitual apenas.

> Mas nesse caso se o servidor de base de dados estiver no mesmo
>   computador que o servidor web, aí seria 2-tier? Ou o que conta é que
>   são processos separados?

Neste caso continua sendo 3 camadas ("3 tiers") pois os conceitos de servidor web e de servidor de banco de dados estão fisicamente separados e este sistema foi arquitetado para de fato ser implantado utilizando diferentes servidores.

Arquitetura N-Tier tornou-se trivial e muito comum, por isso este termo está quase em desuso. Exemplos de software que não são N-Tier:

- Aplicativos desenvolvidos em Clipper.
- Aplicativos desenvolvidos em MS Access (quase sempre é uma única camada/tier).
- Aplicativos desenvolvidos em qualquer linguagem que não usem um [SGBD](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados) nem consumam outro serviço remoto para buscar ou persistir seus dados (por exemplo um aplicativo em Java que salve seus dados em XML ou qualquer outro arquivo gerenciado por ele mesmo e não por um outro software).

Um termo muito mais comum hoje em dia é **"Multi-Layer"**, e este sim trata da separação lógica ou conceitual de um sistema, não implicando necessariamente em separação física.

**Atualização:** adicionei abaixo alguma referência.

> É importante entender a distinção entre "layers" e "tiers". "Layers"
>   descreve o agrupamento lógico de funcionalidade e componentes em uma
>   aplicação; enquanto "tiers" descreve a distribuição física da
>   funcionalidade e componentes em servidores, computadores, redes ou
>   locais remotos. Apesar de que ambos "layers" e "tiers" usam o mesmo
>   conjunto de nomes (apresentação, negócio, serviços, e dados),
>   lembre-se que apenas "tiers" implica em separação física. É comum
>   alocar mais de uma "layer" em uma mesma máquina física (mesma "tier").
>   Você pode pensar o termo "tier" como se referindo a padrões de
>   distribuição física como "2 tiers", "3 tiers" e "n tiers".

Fonte: [Microsoft Application Architecture Guide - Layered Application - Notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx#note).

É lógico que a Microsoft não inventou isso mas está apenas aproveitando conceitos definidos há muito tempo.